# Does the Google Slides API allow adding/modifying animations to an object?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

I'm finding that the gSlides animation capability is lacking, so I've decided to see if I could make a script workaround that would be based on what I am suggesting [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zvp9a2Px-oU;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3A(presentations)$20is$3Afirstpost%7Csort:date).

As far as I can tell, this [gSlides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) is used only for generating slides and not for use in the presentation mode.  So the workaround part would be to put the animation code into the presenter notes and then have a menu item in gSlides (which I think can be added by using [gAppsScript API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/)) that would execute a script to generate additional objects based on the animation code.  These objects would have to specifying animation primitives with them, which would initially be `Appear` and `Disappear`, with specific `With previous`, `After previous` and time intervals use to stop everything from happening all at once.

This will require a **big** commitment in learning how to interact with [gSlides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) and [gAppsScript API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/), which are totally new to me.  Before I dive into this endeavour, I briefly scanned the [gSlides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) to see if I can add animations to objects.  At first glance, I don't see anything that references how to add them. If this is not possible, I won't even bother learning the rest.

### Main question

Can someone tell me if adding animation information to an object is even possible?  And if so, what is the API for it?

### Supplementary questions

Also, is there anything I specified in my madness that would suggest that this cannot be done?  Some object count limit or inability for the two APIs not able to work together perhaps?  Suggestions as to where I should focus my attention would also be grateful.

Comment: If you'll check the issue tracker, there is a pending [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80441863) regarding adding animation control to Slides API. You can star that one to help it be noticed by the Googlers.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, nice. I was looking for their bug tracker and couldn't find it.

Comment: Was it the one you are searching for?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, yes it is.